# Batch extract 7z files and use each output as input for another tool

Tags: batch, script, automation, 7-zip, extract

I'm a bit new to scripting and here's what I would like to ask for help with, please. I'm looking for a batch script to be run against cmd.exe.

1. I have a folder with hundreds of .7z archives. Each archive consists of one file. The folder also contains 7-zip.exe and tool.exe used later in the script.
2. Take first archive, extract using 7-zip and place output in *Temp* sub-folder.
3. Use another tool to convert input file in *Temp* and output resulting file to *Processed* sub-folder.
4. The command for the tool in question is ---> tool.exe -i "*path to input file with .abc extension*" -o "*path to output file with .def extension*" -f xxx -c yyy -l z -b zzzzzz <---.
5. Delete source file from *Temp* folder.
6. Move to the next .7z archive and so on.

Thank you very much in advance for help.

Comment: I'm a little confused do you want to create a batch script or a powershell script?

Comment: @RicardoBohner Sorry, right. The bat. batch script to run against cmd.exe. I will update the question.

Comment: do you know the name of the file with *.abc extension or would the script have to find that out?

Comment: The script would need to find that name out automatically after extraction. But I think the goal would be to have only one .abc file in Temp folder at the time.

Comment: And 7-zip.exe is standalone version of 7zip?

Comment: The *.def files go in the main folder same where the 7z files are correct?

Comment: Sure. Making it simple - the standalone 7z.exe in the same folder as all source .7z archives.

Comment: Per #3, the .def file would go to the Processed sub-folder.

Comment: what is the processed subfolder? In my head I simply copied the *.def file to the same folders where the 7z files are. Does the "Processed subfolder have the same name as the *.abc ?

Comment: Thank you for the script. Now, the script does extract the files (although it does extract all the files one after another, not one at a time and then push to tool.exe) but the tool.exe seems to have a problem with this part of the code: -o "%ABCFile%.def". It looks like it thinks the path and file for -o command is missing...

Comment: If I just replace -o "%ABCFile%.def" with "hard-coded" e.g. -o "file.def" then it works, though... Hmm

Comment: OK, it works, if I remove the .def suffix altogether, like so: -o "%ABCFile%" ... Odd, maybe that tool has a problem... But then output file has no extension...

Also, after removing the .def from the code, the files are being processed one at a time... Awesome. But the last issue seems to be the .tmp folders are not being deleted at the end.

Comment: OK, my last response... Just a minor change needed and the original script deletes .tmp folders (remove one %):
rd /q /s "%~1.tmp".
OK, to place converted files in the same folder as 7z files. Thank you very much for help Ricardo!

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't specify any path for the *.def file, I assume if you specify -o "Anyname.def" it should create the output file in the same directory where the tool.exe is....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the info you passed me I guess it would be something like this:

```
@echo off

for %%a in (*.7z) do call :Extract "%%~na" "%%a"

exit

:Extract
md "%~1.tmp"
7-zip.exe x "%~2" -o"%~1.tmp\"
for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "%~1.tmp\*.abc"') do set ABCFile=%%~na

tool.exe -i "%~1.tmp\%ABCFile.abc%" -o "%ABCFile%.def" -f xxx -c yyy -l z -b zzzzzz
rd /q /s "%~1.tmp"
goto :EOF
```